# probability of sum of a group of random numbers

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Maybe stack overflow isn't the place for this, but it's related to a data science project I'm working on.

If I randomly generate a number between 1 and 10.... 10 times, and then total all the numbers, what will the standard deviation of that total be?

I'm pretty sure the mean of the total will be 55.5, but what about the average distance from that mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming (try http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) one could get that mean indeed would be 10*(10+1)/2 = 55, and variance would be
10*(10-1)<sup>2</sup>/12 = 67.5.

Quick test in Python

```
import math
import random

def sample(a, b):
    s = 0.0
    for k in range (0, 10):
        s += random.uniform(a, b)

    return s

random.seed(12345)

a = 1.0
b = 10.0

n = 100000

q  = 0.0
q2 = 0.0
for k in range(0, n):
    v = sample(a, b)
    q  += v
    q2 += v*v

q  /= float(n)
q2 /= float(n)

print(q, q2 - q*q)
```

Prints `55.005828775627684 67.69074422910626`

Std deviation would be `sqrt(67.5)` and equal to about `8.22`